# Plot a curve using the tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to plot the curve shown in the following picture below.[image]

Is there a someone who can help me to draw the  picture using TikZ or PSTricks.

Comment: You will need to give some more informations about what you're struggling with. It's a pretty straightforward drawing, bur unfortunately, without knowing exactly what it is supposed to picture, it's hard to help. What have you already tried?

Comment: The TikZ manual (see CTAN, or https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz/0) starts off with some tutorials, if you study chapter 2 of the manual that will help you drawing something like that.

Comment: I would recommend you use `tikz`. To draw a blue line, with an arrow between coordiantes `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` you can use `\begin{tikzpicture} \draw [blue, ->] (a,b) -- (c,d); \end{tikzpicture}`. If you don't want the arrow, don't specify `->` in the options. To complete your picture just add more `\draw` commands with the appropriate coordinates.  Hopefully, this is enough to get you started. If you get stuck with a specfic problem, please post a question and include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) showing what you have tried so far or how far you got with your drawing.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the functions of your plots your best option would be pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$\uptau 1$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    ylabel=$\uptau 2$,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=10.5,
    ymin=-30,
    ymax=5,
    yticklabels={,,}, % removes ticklabels from y axis
    ytick style={draw=none}, % removes ticks from y axis
    xticklabels={,,}, % removes ticklabels from y axis
    xtick style={draw=none} % removes ticks from y axis
    ]
        \addplot+[orange,no marks,domain=-1:10,samples=100, thick] {(-x/2)+1} node[midway,yshift=0.5cm] {$f1 (\uptau 1)$};
        \addplot+[blue,no marks,domain=-1:10,samples=100, thick] {(-x/2)-10} node[midway,yshift=0.5cm] {$f2 (\uptau 2)$};     
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]